# How to make an EXT4 into NTFS?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, data-recovery

While installing **Ubuntu**, I accidentally made a **NTFS** drive into **EXT4** drive. Then, all the data of that drive was gone.
Can I recover that drive and those data? 
While using Windows 10, I have tried some softwares but, they were paid. I just want to recover that drive and those data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be carefull and don't absolutely use the disk after the wrong format. 
Download Testdisk.
With this software you can save deleted files to a differtent partition or disk.
Good luck

Comment: do I need to use it on windows or on linux?

Comment: Should work on both.. I think best on linux.. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: no problem... later i recovered that partition with "MiniTool partition wizard" from windows.....